# How to parse more than 2 levels in XML with boost

Tags: c++, xml, parsing, boot

I got this code form the boost library.
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/doc/html/boost_propertytree/tutorial.html

This is the xml file they have

```
<debug>
    <filename>debug.log</filename>
    <modules>
        <module>Finance</module>
        <module>Admin</module>
        <module>HR</module>
    </modules>
    <level>2</level>
</debug>
```

The code to load these values and print them is

```
#include <boost/property_tree/ptree.hpp>
#include <boost/property_tree/xml_parser.hpp>
#include <boost/foreach.hpp>
#include <string>
#include <set>
#include <exception>
#include <iostream>

struct debug_settings
{
    std::string m_file;               // log filename
    int m_level;                      // debug level
    std::set<std::string> m_modules;  // modules where logging is enabled
    void load(const std::string &filename);
    void save(const std::string &filename);
};

void debug_settings::load(const std::string &filename)
{

    using boost::property_tree::ptree;
    ptree pt;
    read_xml(filename, pt);
    m_file = pt.get<std::string>("debug.filename");
    m_level = pt.get("debug.level", 0);
    BOOST_FOREACH(ptree::value_type &v, pt.get_child("debug.modules"))
    m_modules.insert(v.second.data());

}

void debug_settings::save(const std::string &filename)
{

    using boost::property_tree::ptree;
    ptree pt;

    pt.put("debug.filename", m_file);

    pt.put("debug.level", m_level);

    BOOST_FOREACH(const std::string &name, m_modules)
    pt.put("debug.modules.module", name,true);

    write_xml(filename, pt);
}

int main()
{
    try
    {
        debug_settings ds;
        ds.load("debug_settings.xml");
        ds.save("debug_settings_out.xml");
        std::cout << "Success\n";
    }
    catch (std::exception &e)
    {
        std::cout << "Error: " << e.what() << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But it gives me an error

/usr/include/boost/property_tree/detail/ptree_implementation.hpp:769: error: request for member ‘put_value’ in ‘tr’, which is of non-class type ‘bool’

Can anyone tell me what I am missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems they have replaced the put () function ... So if I changed the line

"pt.put("debug.modules.module", name,true);"

to

"pt.add("debug.modules.module", name);"

it works fine. Thank you.